# Shared Storage/Caching in Drone CI Runs

Tags: continuous-integration, openapi, openapi-generator, drone.io

I'm trying to dynamically generate a client library off an OpenAPI specification as a build artifact in my Drone CI/CD pipeline and publish it to an Artifactory registry. For numerous reasons this has to happen *in* the service repository that contains the API specification - I can't pop it in another repo that "listens" for changes in the API spec, for example.

I can successfully generate the client and all that jazz, but the issue I have is:
My CI pipeline will generate & publish a "new" version of the client on every merge to master.

This is suboptimal, because the service API might *not* have really changed.

My build step that does the publishing is specified as follows:

```yaml
  - name: publish-ts-library
    image: node
    environment:
      ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME:
        from_secret: ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME
      ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD:
        from_secret: ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD
      RC_RELEASE: false
    commands:
      - bash ./publish-ts-library.sh
    depends_on:
      - build-read-gateway-ts-client
    when:
      branch: master
      event:
        exclude:
        - pull_request
```

The shell script executed is:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

touch .npmrc
curl -u$ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME:$ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD https://mycompany.jfrog.io/mycompany/api/npm/auth > .npmrc
echo "registry=https://mycompany.jfrog.io/mycompany/api/npm/npm" >> .npmrc
if [ $RC_RELEASE ]
then
    sed -i '/version/s/[^.]*$/'"0-dev${DRONE_BUILD_NUMBER}\",/" package.json
else
    sed -i '/version/s/[^.]*$/'"0.${DRONE_BUILD_NUMBER}\",/" package.json
fi
npm publish
```

I know it's pretty gross, apologies.

What's happening is pretty simple: we grab some auth credentials from the secrets in Drone, and pop them in a .npmrc file. Then, if it's an RC release we add `dev` to the version, else we just bump the version to whatever the drone build number is.

So, my initial thinking was to take a `sha1sum` of the OpenAPI spec yaml file that I use to generate the library, and compare it to the sha of the "last" generated client - if it matches then no-op instead of `npm publish`, but the kicker is I have no idea where I can store this SHA, and how to configure drone to have access to this storage.

I'm aware of plugins like http://plugins.drone.io/drillster/drone-volume-cache/ - but they seem decidedly ephemeral, I need to be assured that this SHA will be persisted across builds consistently, and not suddenly "vanish" because a cache gets cleared, thereby forcing a republish + bump of an otherwise identical generated client.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with drone ci, so I'm making a couple of assumptions here:

- `git`, `awk`, and `wc` are available in the context the script is executed.

If it is certain that the workflow will always be based on a `git merge`, then it is possible to use the diff between the merge's commit and the merge's first parent commit hashes to determine if changes where made to the relevant files.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Returns the commit sha of the first parent (merge target) of the last git merge
getMergeCommitBase () {
    git rev-parse HEAD | \
    git rev-list --parents --min-parents=2 -n1 --stdin | \
    awk '{print $2}'
}

exitIfTheseFilesHaveNotChanged () {
    local count
    count="$(git diff "$(getMergeCommitBase)" "$@" | wc -l | awk '{print $1}')"
    if [ "$count" == "0" ]
    then
        echo "no version changes detected"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "changes detected - publishing new version"
    fi
}

# If any of these files have changed, we want to publish a new version
exitIfTheseFilesHaveNotChanged path/to/file.json path/to/directory/

# the rest is your original script

touch .npmrc
curl -u$ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME:$ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD https://mycompany.jfrog.io/mycompany/api/npm/auth > .npmrc
echo "registry=https://mycompany.jfrog.io/mycompany/api/npm/npm" >> .npmrc
if [ $RC_RELEASE ]
then
    sed -i '/version/s/[^.]*$/'"0-dev${DRONE_BUILD_NUMBER}\",/" package.json
else
    sed -i '/version/s/[^.]*$/'"0.${DRONE_BUILD_NUMBER}\",/" package.json
fi
npm publish
```

Hope the idea helps.